# Praying after chatzot– which tefilot?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, shacharis-morning-prayer, sleep

Assume that someone wakes up after chatzot; which tefilot are said?

Comment: One cannot daven after chatzot?

Comment: @sam One cannot say birchot shema after chatzot, see elsehwere here, I forget where it's asked.

Comment: See the Shulchan Aruch 89:1 with Mishna Brurah 7 one should not daven after chatzos,even though there is shittos who allow within the half hour ,still it should not be done ayin sham

Comment: What about on Rosh Chodesh, concerning מוסף and הלל?

Comment: IIRC Musaf can be said all day. If on Yom Kippur, you finish Shaharit so late that the time for Mincha has arrived, you have to say Mincha first and afterwards Musaf. For that reason, the Shat"z is instructed not to drag things out that much and make sure he starts Musaf well before the time for Mincha.

Comment: He can't say *baruch sheomar*, *yishtabach*, *birchos krias shema*, and *shemoneh esreh*, but other than that the rest is primarily pesukim - you can say that all day.